# Access vSphere 5, ESXi, Virtual Machine environment: processes, file system

Tags: c#, vmware

We have a vSphere 5 Hypervisor that runs few Windows XP/Vista/7 virtual machines with VMWare tools installed on each.

Would like to be able to:

1. power on a VM by its name
2. connect an ISO image from a local machine to a powered on VM
3. copy few files to a VM, to a specific folder (NANT and NUNIT
   binaries and dlls with tests)
4. run a just copied executable and wait till it completes
5. get a file from a TEMP folder, which path has to be determined by
   reading an Environment variable of a VM
6. determine whether or not a particular process is running inside VM

I would like to use VmWare.Vim.dll which is a part of a VmWare Infrastructure (VI) toolkit. I code in C# and .NET 4.
Power on/off operations I could do easily, but what about others? I have no clue how to do these operations. Haven't found anything in documentation.
Perhaps there are other tools/API that could help me?

Previously we used VixCOM and Vestris.VmWareLib wrapper, but we had a simple VMWare Workstation. Now we moved to a vSphere and these API don't work.

Best Regards,
Alex

Comment: VIX is still the answer for anything inside the VM.  Perhaps you need a newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at vSphere Web Services SDK:
GuestFileManager, 
GuestOperationsManager and 
GuestProcessManager (http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer like yourself, do manage a VM envt. To do what you're looking to do is certainly possible with the API/SDK provided by VMware (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/index.html), but there may be an easier way. One way to do this would be with PowerCLi which is a snapin for PowerShell, which as you probably know, is based upon C# and can import its libraries.

You could then do something like this and be well on your way:

```
#start VM
Start-VM -VM $vmName

#mount ISO file
Get-VM -Name $vmName | Get-CDDrive | Set-CDDrive -v -IsoPath <ISO-file-name> -Confirm:$false

#copy files
Copy-Item -Path $somePath -Destination $someDestination

#invoke 'script' that will run .exe file (example exe below)
$script = '"%programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe" /report "%tmp%\inforeport"'
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script -VM VM -HostCredential $hostCredential -GuestCredential $guestCredential -ScriptType Bat

#check for list of processes running
$script2 = '"WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid"'
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script2 -VM VM -HostCredential $hostCredential -GuestCredential $guestCredential -ScriptType Bat
```

Hope this is of some help

Answer (score 0):

We managed to create a NANT task that operates vSphere Virtual Machines.
Thanks for tips guys!

Comment: LucID, I have the same scenario at work and trying to achieve the same goal using vSphere 5.0 API and .Net Framework 3.5 (C#). I am using Vmware.Vim.dll too. I was able to do some other vSphere operations and tasks. I am stuck at Vm guest operations with the same scenario. Could you explain a little more about your solution and how you solved it ? Thanks.